# I am working on a time-series data. How do I sum time of a particular day?

Tags: dataframe, time-series, data-science

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJhBV.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL5SZ.png)

the image contains a dataset having machine id and timeinstance as columns and i have to calculate the total time a machine is working for each day.

Comment: please copy paste the sample data in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
t1 = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015 01:00')

t2 = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2015 03:30')

#in seconds
print pd.Timedelta(t2 - t1).seconds / 3600.0

#in hours
print pd.Timedelta(t2 - t1).seconds / 60.0
```

Comment: But i have to calculate time for a many number of days. How do i do this???

Comment: machineid timeinstance
0 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:43.836
1 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:43.835
2 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:42.836
3 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:42.833
4 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:41.832
5 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:41.831
6 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:39.848
7 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:39.843
8 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:38.835
9 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:37.848
10 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:37.835
11 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:36.847
12 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:36.846
13 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:34.838
14 5018 2019-01-16 04:47:34.837